# How to open a pptx file using shell script

Tags: shell, powerpoint, powershell-3.0

I am trying to open a pptx file using shell script. I have tried following commands
    `catppt` and `catdoc`. It's not working.

Is there any other command?

Comment: catppt is apparently intended to work with .PPT files; .PPTX files have a totally different format.  Google catppt pptx for a few suggestions though.

Comment: What do you mean by "open"? Launch PowerPoint and immediately open the file, the same as if you  double-clicked it in Explorer? Are you doing this on Windows (where `catppt` may or may not even exist), or another OS (in which case PowerShell won't be there)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file extension .pptx is associated with the correct program (PowerPoint, I assume), you can just use Invoke-Item cmdlet in Powershell.

For example :

```
Invoke-Item -Path C:\Path\To\MyFile.pptx
```

Invoke-Item automatically uses the appropriate program to open the file, depending on how the file association is configured in the "Default Programs" control panel.

Answer (score 1):

Besides `Invoke-Item`, you can also use `Start-Process` and `&` to [open powerpoint (.pptx) file from PowerShell](https://www.byteinthesky.com/powershell/how-to-open-powerpoint-file-using-powershell).

For example:

```
Start-Process 'C:\Path\To\MyFile.pptx'
```

Or

```
& 'C:\Path\To\MyFile.pptx'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way if you have multiple programs that will open a .pptx file or don't have PowerPoint registered as the default handler for the .pptx file type.

`$pptx = "{path to file}"`

`$application = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application`

`$presentation = $application.Presentations.open($pptx)`

`$application.visible = "msoTrue"`

`$presentation.SlideShowSettings.Run()`